# What's wrong with my power function which takes 2 as base, n as exponent and computes answer modulo 10^9+7?

Tags: c++, exponentiation

**My code:**

```
int power(int n)
{
    int num = 1000000007;
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n%2 == 1)
    {
        int storage = power((n-1)/2);
        return (2*storage*storage)%num;
    }
    int storage = power(n/2);
    return (storage*storage)%num;
}
```

I have used [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to make it more efficient, I know that something is wrong because the output to `n= 1000` generates `495105785` whereas the correct answer is `688423210`.

I even tried changing the return datatype to long long to check possible overflow that may occur in lines `9` and `12`, but the answer remained the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storage * storage` may overflow `int` value sometimes, e.g. if storage is 2^30 then `storage * storage` is 2^60 which will be truncated to `int` to fit into 2^32 but you want full-size computation otherwise you'll get wrong remainder. Use `int64_t` for intermediate results, like in code below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDbCsIwDEDf@xUBEVZhuA3Rh23@ipSujsKWjV7wQfz2mdo5L6B5atKTkxA5jqnsBLbTtNIoO98oqKR1jUZ3ZK@SHqwzSvRH5q3GFlD0yo5CKiC2ZIxwGIeLMkl4IWdXBhSU7HcnKvgeasizOQ5l/D1DglDXkPFHHsIo5w1C/k6soQhUHqnrwj7t1g1GtIomxBWoJSUatlDw8tucFLBZOpYXpyG0ZKRv7J8d37xP52/fLd6mFxoTPu8uB@@gqmZfuAoPqcKm@9Bm1D5Ndw)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int power(int n)
{
    int64_t num = 1000000007;
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 1)
    {
        int64_t storage = power((n - 1) / 2);
        return (2 * storage * storage) % num;
    }
    int64_t storage = power(n / 2);
    return (storage * storage) % num;
}

int main() {
    cout << power(1000) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1000
```

Output:

```
688423210
```

Comment: So you are saying that since I have declared `storage` to be `int` the intermediate `storage*storage` will be stored as `int` only? Even though I have set the return type to `long long`?

Comment: @AradhyeAgarwal No, I'm saying that if storage equals to 2^30 then `storage * storage` will be 2^60 which will be truncated to 2^32 but you don't want truncation, you want whole 2^60 calculation.

Comment: @AradhyeAgarwal Not only return type should be long long, but also all intermediate computations that may overflow.

Comment: @AradhyeAgarwal In fact you may leave return type as int, only intermediate multiplication and division should be done as int-64. Because result is always within 32 bits, while intermediate results may be 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

`storage * storage` may overflow if int is 32 bit or smaller. Use overflow safe calculation.

One alternative could be `(int)(storage * 1LL * storage % num)` and similar for odd power case.